# How can I change from input to label in angularjs based on authorization

Tags: angularjs

I have an existing application with some input fields. Now I need to change the input to label depending on user authorization. For e.g, I need to display it as input itself if the user have ADMIN role, if not I need to display as label.
I know it can be done using ng-switch or ng-if, in that case I will need to make changes in all fields. What I'm looking for is a solution with minimal changes, say declaring a directive and add it to all input fields. And in runtime I can get the user role from Service.

Is there any solution for that? May be something with http interceptor.

Please help.

I declared one directive as below,

```
alphaModule.directive('alphaField', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template : '<span >{{ model }}</span>'
                + '<input type="type" class="alphaClass" ng-model="model" $scope.required minlength="minlength"/>',
        scope : {
            model : '=model',
            type: '=type',
            alphaClass: '&alphaclass',
            minlength: '=minlength',
            required: '=required'
        },
        controller : function($scope) {}
    };
});
```

Then in the page,

```
<alpha-field model="event.description" type="text" alphaclass="form-control"  minlength="5" required="required" ></alpha-field>
```

After doing this, the model is binding correctly. But not other values like class, type etc...

Comment: 1. create a service for all authentication stuff - 2. create a directive that wraps the input and label - 3. inject your auth service to the directive and let it decide what to show to the user

Comment: Thanks @Alp, That's exactly the idea in my mind. As my directive should be re-usable for all components, do you know how we can get the model, placeholder, class, style etc from the page(component declaration) to the directive?

Comment: the model should reside in a `$resource`, probably served by another service. also the model, placeholder, class and style can be directly set in the directive like so: `<dynamic-input model="myModel" placeholder="myPlaceholder" type="textarea"></dynamic-input>` - just an example

Comment: @Alp, Please see my code above. Could you please help?

Comment: Kamrul already gave the correct answer. "=" expects an expression, "@" excepts a string and "&" expects a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try...

```
alphaModule.directive('alphaField', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template : '<span >{{ model }}</span>'
                + '<input type="{{type}}" class="{{alphaClass}}" ng-model="model" $scope.required minlength="{{minlength}}"/>',
        scope : {
            model : '=model',
            type: '@',
            alphaClass: '@',
            minlength: '@',
            required: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
            console.log(scope.type, scope.alphaClass, scope.minlength, scope.required);  
        }
    };
});
```